# When I run a code on a raspberry pi pico w using vscode, the pico w is disconnected

Tags: visual-studio-code, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to test raspberry pi pico w on window but every single time i run the code, the pico w is disconnected automately. So I connected on my mac and runned, and it works.

With the same code, with the same extensions, but only on window it does not work.

The code I used is

```
from machine import Pin
from utime import sleep

pin = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)

print("LED starts flashing...")
while True:
    try:
        pin.toggle()
        sleep(1) # sleep 1sec
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
pin.off()
print("Finished.")
```

The Error statement is `Exception occured (maybe a connection loss)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am6lZ.png)

What would be the problem?

I need to get some solution to make it works on my window laptop as well.

And want to know what I did wrong or any problem.